# Adding an edge in Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, charts, graph-theory, floyd-warshall

Assume we have computed the all-pairs distance matrix in a graph using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. How can we efficiently update this distance matrix when a new edge is added?

We can of course rerun the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, but that will take O(V<sup>3</sup>). Can we make it faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say the edge goes from vertex **v** to vertex **w** and has cost **c**:

If the distance matrix already has a shorter path from v to w, then adding the edge has no effect, so there's nothing to do.

Otherwise, the new edge becomes the shortest path from **v** to **w**, so enter it into the distance matrix, and then, for every other pair of vertices **a** and **b**, see if it can be made shorter by using the new edge.  From the distance matrix you can easily find the cost of **a-v-w-b** and **a-w-v-b**.  Note that one **a** or **b** might by the same as **v** or **w**.

Since you have to check every pair of vertices, this takes O(V<sup>2</sup>) time.